# Error in the Layout setting

Tags: android, android-layout

Right now I have a layout as in the picture, just that I would like the blue rectangle inside the white rectangle I go to fill the whole size of the white square .. but I tried to change some settings but not works.

The Xml is:

```
    <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:context=".LoginActivity" >


    <!-- Login progress -->

    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/login_status"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
           style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/login_status_message"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
           android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
           android:text="@string/login_progress_signing_in"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Login form -->

    <ScrollView
       android:id="@+id/login_form"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@color/background_color" >



        <LinearLayout
           style="@style/LoginFormContainer"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:background="@color/background_login_color"
           android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/row0"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/top_logo_repeat"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageLogo"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:antialias="true"
           android:contentDescription="@string/logoimg"
           android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
               android:id="@+id/username"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:hint="@string/prompt_username"
               android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

               android:maxLines="1"
               android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
               android:id="@+id/password"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
               android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
               android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
               android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
               android:inputType="textPassword"
               android:maxLines="1"
               android:singleLine="true" />

            <CheckBox
               android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@string/saveCheckBox" />

            <Button
               android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
               android:paddingLeft="32dp"
               android:paddingRight="32dp"
               android:text="@string/action_sign_in_register" />

            <Button
               android:id="@+id/button1"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sign_in_button"
               android:layout_weight="0.30"
               android:text="@string/registerButton" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</merge>
```

[image: Screen Layout]

Comment: more clarity needed...

Comment: I want the blue rectangle has the width of the white rectangle, if known to the right and to the left of the blue rectangle there is white space

Comment: which blue rectangle and which white rectangle,,,,can u pls be a bit clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your linearLayout has style set to `LoginFormContainer`

```
<LinearLayout
       style="@style/LoginFormContainer"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:background="@color/background_login_color"
       android:orientation="vertical" >
```

In this style, it is likely that margins are set. As such, all contents in the `LinearLayout` have a margin.

The solution to this, is to **remove the margin from the style**. (Or remove the style from the `LinearLayout`.

Note: This will then remove the margins to the `editText` etc below the image too, as they are also in the linear layout.

The solution to fix this, would be to wrap the rest of the contents in its own `LinearLayout` and apply the margin to this `LinearLayout`.